# How should I cite this talk and its (slightly different) notes?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a small paper (just an independent study for an undergraduate course, nothing more) and I came across [this talk](http://www.birs.ca/events/2014/5-day-workshops/14w5101/videos/watch/201401231116-Vardi.html) and [these notes from that talk](http://www.lsv.fr/Events/fmt2012/SLIDES/moshevardi.pdf).

The trouble is, the notes are two years older than the video, and they are not the exact notes used in the video. Should they then be cited separately? If not, should I leave a note saying that they're slightly different?

This is what I have now:

```
@misc{vardi,
    author="Moshe Vardi",
    title ="Phase Transitions and Computational Complexity",
    year  ="2014",
    note  ="Video talk with slides (slides are older than video and do not
    contain the full content of those actually used in the video). 
    Video accessed 2018-03-23 from 
    \url{http://www.birs.ca/events/2014/5-day-workshops/14w5101/videos/watch/201401231116-Vardi.html},
    slides accessed 2018-03-23 from 
    \url{http://www.lsv.fr/Events/fmt2012/SLIDES/moshevardi.pdf}"
}
```

Is such a long note necessary? Should the URLs be in `howPublished`? Should both access dates be there? If not, which one? (They are the same but if they weren't, which one?) Should I include the year for the slides as well? Should I *only* include the year for the slides?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You raise some very interesting and important questions. :-) Some comments:

- Do keep the `year` field.
- I'd create a separate `howpublished` field, to contain the string `Video talk with slides`.
- I'd reorganize the `note` field to first mention the URLs (and the dates they were accessed) of the video and of the slides. Only then would I mention that the published slides aren't identical to the ones that are featured in the video. That's probably (more than) enough information for even the most punctilious reader.
- A subject you haven't raised so far is: Are the slides employed in the video and those available online substantively different? Do they maybe even contain contradictory material? Or is it just a matter of (relative) completeness? If there's a material difference, are you basing your citation primarily on the video's slides or those available separately? If there's a substantive difference and if it's worth pointing out that there's a difference, you should probably provide two separate bibliographic entries, one for the video and one for the slides. For sure, doing so will make it easier for your readers to follow along with what exactly you're referencing.

Here's a suggested re-write that doesn't assume it's necessary to provide two separate bibliographic entries:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{vardi,
    author="Moshe Vardi",
    title ="Phase Transitions and Computational Complexity",
    year  = 2014,
    howpublished = "Video talk with slides",
    note  ="Video accessed 2018-03-23 from 
           \url{http://www.birs.ca/events/2014/5-day-workshops/14w5101/videos/watch/201401231116-Vardi.html}.
           Slides available separately, accessed 2018-03-23, at 
           \url{http://www.lsv.fr/Events/fmt2012/SLIDES/moshevardi.pdf}.
           Note: The slides available online are older than the video, 
           and they do not contain the full content of the slides 
           actually used in the video."
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces,hyphens]{url}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or some other suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\nocite{vardi}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```